# Recursive definition of a palindrome

Tags: combinatorics, palindrome

I have an alphabet $A =$ {0,1} and I want to find a recursive definition for the function $f(n)$ = {$v$: $v$ is a palindrome of length $n$ formed by characters of $A$}. I also want to find the size of this set (the number of palindromes of lenght $n$ formed by characters of $A$).

My thoughts are:

1. λ (empty word) is a palindrome.
2. For any $a_i$ ∈ $A$, $a_i$ is a palindrome.
3. If $v$ a palindrome and $a_i$ ∈ $A$, then $a_ika_i$ is a palindrome.

What would my recursive definition be and how can  I find the number of palindromes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A recursive definition of $f$ (for any alphabet $A$) should be something like this: 
$$f(n) = \begin{cases} \{\lambda\} &\mbox{if } n = 0 \\
A &\mbox{if } n = 1\\
\{ava : a \in A, v \in f(n - 2) \} &\mbox{if } n > 1
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Shouldn't it be $a$ instead of $A$ for the case when $n=1$?

Comment: @user132335 no, what is $a$? The only words of length $1$ are the characters of $A$, therefore the set of words of length $1$ is... $A$! (Note that I'm considering characters to be words of length $1$)

Comment: $a$ is a character of $A$. I'm confused because I'm considering $A$ as the alphabet {1,0}, so $a$ would be $1$ or $2$.

Comment: @user132335 You mean $a$ would be $0$ or $1$? You probably want to write something like $\{a: a \in A\}$ right? Well that's equal to $A$ $\ddot \smile$. Or you could just simply write $\{0, 1\}$ instead

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial answer only concerned with the number of palindromes.

The number of palindromes of length 0 is 1. The number of palindromes of length 1 is 2 (namely 0, 1).

If $k$ is a palindrome of length $n$, then $0k0$ and $1k1$ are the only possible palindromes of length $n+2$, which doubles the number of palindromes from going from length $n$ to length $n+2$.

Thus, if we denote the number of palindromes of length $n$ by $g(n)$, we have $$g(n)=2g(n-2), \ n=2,\dots$$

For the exact number, we get different formulas for even and odd numbers: $$g(2k)=2^k\cdot g(0)=2^k, \quad g(2k+1)=2^k \cdot g(1)=2^{k+1}.$$

Comment: So my recursive definition would be $f(n)=2f(n−2)$ and the size $2^k + 2^{k+1}$?

Comment: @user132335: Please note that my the function in the answer is **not** the function which maps to the set of all palindromes, it merely calculates their number. See the answer of dani_s for the actual $f$. I will change my notation from $f$ to $g$ to avoid confusion.