# Can I compute the number of numbers that don't change values when you flip them over?

Tags: combinatorics

Let $\mathbb{A}$ = {0,1,6,8,9} be the set of single integer values that when flipped upside down are equivalent to another integer.  (Please ignore the fact that one is not a straight line.)  Let $\mathbb{B}$ be the set of Integers such that flipping the entire number over does not change its value.  For example 1961 turned over is equal to 1961.  There are obviously 3 one digit numbers in $\mathbb{B}$--namely 0, 1, and 8.  There are three two digit numbers in $\mathbb{B}$--namely 11, 69, and 88.  I think there are twelve three digit numbers in $\mathbb{B}$--namely 101, 111, 181, 609, 619, 689, 808, 818, 888, 906, 916, 986.  Calculating the number of N digit values in $\mathbb{B}$ seems like a basic combinatorics question.

Obviously you only need to select the ceiling of half of N.  You must select from 5 objects and the final digit you select must exclude the 6 or the nine if you are on an odd location.  I guess what I am saying is I lack the mathematical prowess to express this though in mathematical terms.  Can someone assist me?

Comment: You seem to be using "turn over" in the sense of "rotate by $180^\circ$" instead of "mirror vertically" in which case you may wish to include the digits $2,5$ in your list.

Comment: This question is closely related to the palindromic numbers, ask asked e.g. here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/695298/recursive-definition-of-a-palindrome 

The main difference is that composing a palindromic number of length $n+2$ is done by taking a palindromic number of length $n$ and pre- and postappending the same digit, whereas a flip-number of length $n+2 $ is composed by a flip-number of length $n$ an and preappending one character, and postappending its flipped character.

Comment: @Roland: Not quite. For example, the number 80008 doesn’t come from a 3-digit flip-number, unless you consider 000 a three-digit number, and that’s not how “$n$-digit number” is usually understood.

Comment: @SteveKass: Indeed. Leading zeros need to be taken into account. With my approach, I was not considering these numbers as numbers, but rather as strings or words. Leading zeros have to be excluded after doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you want to find $F(n)$, the number of $n$ digit numbers in $\mathbb{B}$.  We can state that $n = 2k$ for some integer $k$.  For any $k$-digit number made out of digits in $\mathbb{A}$, we can add the unique complementary string to make an $n$-digit number in $\mathbb{B}$.

For example, take $n = 6$, so that $k = 3$. $698$ is a number made from the digits of $\mathbb{A}$.  Adding on the digits $869$, we now have $698869 \in \mathbb{B}$.

Since every $n$-digit number in $\mathbb{B}$ can be uniquely constructed in this manner, we simply need to count the number of $k$-digit numbers we can make out of the digits in $\mathbb{A}$.  That is, if $n$ is even, we have (excluding numbers with leading zeros)
$$
F(n) = 4\times \overbrace{5 \times \cdots \times 5}^{k-1} = 5^{(n/2)-1}
$$
Now... what if $n$ is odd?  *Hint: consider the middle-digit separately*.

In the end of the day, we should have
$$
F(n) = 
\begin{cases}
4 \times 5^{(n-2)/2} & n \text{ is even}\\
12 \times 5^{(n-3)/2} & n \text{ is odd}
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: You’re counting 0000, 0960, etc., as four-digit numbers, which is not usually done. If someone asked you “How many four-digit numbers are divisible by 2?”, I don’t think you would count 0012, 0176, etc.

Comment: @SteveKass good point, fixed accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

There are 4, not 3, two-digit numbers in $\mathbb B$. (You left out 96.). You can calculate the number for larger $N$ if you look at even and odd $N$ separately.

Here are two examples. If you know all the 6-digit flippable numbers, you can find all the 7-digit ones by inserting a 0, 1, or 8 into the middle of a six-digit one. So there are three times as many 7-digit ones as 6-digit ones.

If you want all the 10-digit flippable numbers, start with the 8-digit ones, and squeeze any of the 4 two-digit flippable numbers (11,88, 96, or 69) or 00 into the middle. So there are 5 times as many.

In other words, if $f(N)$ is the number of flippable $N$-digit numbers, then $f(N) = 3f(N-1)$ when $N$ is odd, and $f(N) = 5f(N-2)$ when $N$ is even.

That gives this as the sequence of how many there are for each integer length, starting with 2 (so we don't have to quibble over whether 0 counts): 4,12,20,60,100,...

I hope I didn't get this wrong. The reason I'm worried is that the sequence I get for the number of n-digit [strobogrammatic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strobogrammatic_number) numbers, as they're called [isn't in the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](https://oeis.org/search?q=4,12,20,60&sort=&language=&go=Search).

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you want a digit of length $n$, which is even. You choose the first $\frac n2$ digits randomly, now this choice completely determines the remaining digits. You should be careful not to choose a number starting with zero, but then the answer is quite clear.